# How to add prefix and suffix to certain vocabulary term names

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms

I have vocabulary *Height*, with terms 50, 100, 150, etc.
On the Taxonomy page, I want the title "Height 50 mm", "Height 100 mm", "Height 150 mm" etc.
I know it must be something like this, but the code doesn`t work for me; it applies the change to all taxonomy, not just my terms.

```
<?php
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term') {
    $tid = arg(2);
    $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
    $name = t('Height !name mm', array('!name' => $term->name));
    $vars['title'] = $name;
  }
}
?>
```

How can I apply the title change only to my height vocabulary?

Comment: Does that code work at least getting the fields of each term? Or you are just saying its not adding the "mm" but still receiving all data from the term?

Comment: That code work fine with all terms. But i need solution for one certain vocabulary.

Comment: Then if the code works fine, whats wrong with a term? I'm not following you, please be more specific about the error u have

Comment: I'm dunno how to explain but i'll try all of my best. This code must work with one specific vocabulary, that what i mean. But instead it work with all term all vocabularies, that the problem i have.

Comment: Next time, be clear about what you need, if you need to know the definition about a function, just ask for it, and do not write, "the code doesn't work for me", because that leads to a bug that your having ...

Comment: You right. I am will try to avoid such a misundersdandable situation like this. Thank you for your participation and involvement, it helps formulate (declare, express) the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`taxonomy_term_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7.x) loads a taxonomy object with the `vid` property. You can use that in your logic to target specific vocabulary in your preprocess function. For example:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term') {
    $tid = arg(2);

    // Only alter if we have a valid taxonomy.
    if ($term = taxonomy_term_load($tid)) {

       // Check that the taxonomy is a part of vocab ID = 1
       // @TODO: replace 1 with specified vocabulary ID.
       if ($term->vid == 1) {
         $name = t('Height !name mm', array('!name' => $term->name));
         $vars['title'] = $name;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No problem. If this solved your problem make sure to make it as solved (the check mark next to the question).

Comment: It is possible instead of text in prefix paste vocabulary name and make code working for several vocabularies and looking something like 
`if ($term->vid == 1 && $term->vid == 2) {
         $name = t('!vocabulary !name mm', array('!name' => $term->name,'!vocabulary' =>$vocabulary->name));
         $vars['title'] = $name;
       }`